# How to write a Pandas Dataframe to existing Django model

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pandas

I am trying to insert data in a Pandas DataFrame into an existing Django model, `Agency`, that uses a SQLite backend. However, following the answers on [How to write a Pandas Dataframe to Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425607/how-to-write-a-pandas-dataframe-to-django-model?rq=1) and [Saving a Pandas DataFrame to a Django Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688054/saving-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-django-model) leads to the whole SQLite table being replaced and breaking the Django code. Specifically, it is the Django auto-generated `id` primary key column that is replaced by `index` that causes the errors when rendering templates (`no such column: agency.id`).

Here is the code and the result of using Pandas to_sql on the SQLite table, `agency`.

In `models.py`:

```
class Agency(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

In `myapp/management/commands/populate.py`:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

def handle(self, *args, **options):

    # Open ModelConnection
    from django.conf import settings
    database_name = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
    database_url = 'sqlite:///{}'.format(database_name)
    engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=False)

    # Insert data data
    agencies = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Agency 1", "Agency 2", "Agency 3"]})
    agencies.to_sql("agency", con=engine, if_exists="replace")
```

Calling '`python manage.py populate`' successfully adds the three agencies into the table:

```
index    name
0        Agency 1
1        Agency 2
2        Agency 3
```

However, doing so has changed the DDL of the table from:

```
CREATE TABLE "agency" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL)
```

to:

```
CREATE TABLE agency (
  "index" BIGINT, 
  name TEXT
);
CREATE INDEX ix_agency_index ON agency ("index")
```

How can I add the DataFrame to the model managed by Django and keep the Django ORM intact?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer my own question, as I import data using Pandas into Django quite often nowadays, the mistake I was making was trying to use Pandas built-in Sql Alchemy DB ORM which was modifying the underlying database table definition. In the context above, you can simply use the Django ORM to connect and insert the data:

```
from myapp.models import Agency

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        # Process data with Pandas
        agencies = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Agency 1", "Agency 2", "Agency 3"]})

        # iterate over DataFrame and create your objects
        for agency in agencies.itertuples():
            agency = Agency.objects.create(name=agency.name)
```

However, you may often want to import data using an external script rather than using a management command, as above, or using Django's shell. In this case you must first connect to the Django ORM by calling the `setup` method:

```
import os, sys

import django
import pandas as pd

sys.path.append('../..') # add path to project root dir
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myproject.settings"

# for more sophisticated setups, if you need to change connection settings (e.g. when using django-environ):
#os.environ["DATABASE_URL"] = "postgres://myuser:mypassword@localhost:54324/mydb"

# Connect to Django ORM
django.setup()

# process data
from myapp.models import Agency
Agency.objects.create(name='MyAgency')
```

- Here I have exported my settings module `myproject.settings` to the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` so that `django.setup()` can pick up the project settings.
- Depending on where you run the script from, you may need to path to the system path so Django can find the settings module. In this case, I run my script two directories below my project root.
- You can modify any settings before calling `setup`. If your script needs to connect to the DB differently than whats configured in `settings`. For example, when running a script locally against  Django/postgres Docker containers.

Note, the above example was using the [django-environ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-environ) to specify DB settings.

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for a more performant and up-to-date solution, I would suggest using `manager.bulk_create` and instantiating the django model instances, but not creating them.

```
model_instances = [Agency(name=agency.name) for agency in agencies.itertuples()]
Agency.objects.bulk_create(model_instances)
```

Note that `bulk_create` does not run signals or custom saves, so if you have custom saving logic or signal hooks for `Agency` model, that will not be triggered. Full list of caveats below.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are still looking for the answer, Now pandas.to_sql() method has an additional parameter called index_label. If you set index=True, then you can also set a label for that index column. I set

```
df.to_sql('YOUR_TABLE',index=True,index_label='id' ,con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

I tested this with one of my Django projects and it worked for me.
[Check out the docs for more info.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)